# App Crashes when try to set the maximumValue to the UISlider

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avkit

When I am trying to play the video I am getting this exception below.

> *** Assertion failure in -[CustomSlider _setValue:minValue:maxValue:andSendAction:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore/UIKit-3698.119.2/UISlider.m:1477
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempting to set a slider's minimumValue (0.000000) to be larger than the maximumValue (nan)'
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

**This is my code:**

This piece of code is working fine when I run on the iOS 13 devices but getting crash when I run this on the iOS 12.3.1 device.

**SDK:** iOS 13
**Tool:** XCode 11.3.1
**Target Device:** iPhone 6S Plus running iOS 12.3.1

```
func updateUIforPlayerItemStatus() {
    guard let currentItem = player.currentItem else { return }
    
    switch currentItem.status {        
    case .readyToPlay:
        playPauseButton.isEnabled = true
        guard player.currentItem!.duration >= CMTime.zero else {
            return
        }
        
        let newDurationSeconds = Float(currentItem.duration.seconds)
        
        let currentTime = Float(player.currentTime().seconds)
        timeSlider.minimumValue = 0.0
        timeSlider.maximumValue = newDurationSeconds
        timeSlider.value = currentTime
        timeSlider.isEnabled = true
        durationLabel.isEnabled = true
        durationLabel.text = createTimeString(time: newDurationSeconds)
        player.playImmediately(atRate: playbackRate)            
        
    default:
        playPauseButton.isEnabled = false
        timeSlider.isEnabled = false
        durationLabel.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: check currentItem.duration.seconds value. seems it is 0

Comment: all the video assets I am using have time more than 2 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says that `maximumValue` is NaN (not-a-number), which means `newDurationSeconds` is not a number, which means `currentItem.duration.seconds` is not a number. Check to make sure it's not NaN before using it, like this:

```
[...]
guard currentItem.duration >= .zero, !currentItem.duration.seconds.isNaN else {
    return
}

let newDurationSeconds = Float(currentItem.duration.seconds)

[...]
```

Answer (score 2):

The slider's maximum value is nan which means the duration of your avPlayer is indefinite, you can get an estimate using:

```
    let newDurationSeconds = Float(currentItem.asset.duration.seconds ?? 00)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error comes when duration is to be .Nan, Use this code to fix it

```
        if let duration = musicPlayer.instance.player.currentItem?.duration {
            guard duration.isNaN else {
                return
            }
            let seconds : Float64 = duration
        self.sliderAudio.maximumValue = Float(seconds)
        }
```